Bash groups expanded array with adjacent strings
Testcase:
#!/bin/bash

params=(-l -t -a)
sudo "ls ${params[@]} -r"

Outcome:
> bash -x test.sh 
+ params=(-l -t -a)
+ sudo 'ls -l' -t '-a -r'
sudo: ls -l: No such file or directory

Why are adjacent strings grouped with the first and last array element?
Can this be easily/reasonably prevented to work as intended - keep the expanded array separate?
Naive approaches like sudo "ls ""${params[@]}"" -r" or sudo 'ls '"${params[@]}"' -r' do not seem to work.
Please note that sudo is used only to illustrate the principle - the string grouping is the concern.

Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables! There are many situations in which people try to shove commands, or command arguments, into variables and then run them. Each case needs to be handled separately. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Do you want sudo ls "${params[@]}" -r? sudo does not expect a single string, it expects many arguments. A comment, not an answer, because it does not answer "why?". Besides, you wrote that "sudo is used only to illustrate the principle - the string grouping is the concern", but you did not tell us what exact string(s) you wanted (expected) to get. Please [edit] and add this information.

Note that the debug output of set -x doesn't actually mean that bash is adding single quotes to the actual command or arguments. Bash needs some way to show that parts of the debug output are a single string even if separated by white space, and it uses single quotes to do so. If you ran echo "foo bar" with set -x, the debug outout would be echo 'foo bar', but of course the real output would be just foo bar, not 'foo bar'.

I find using printf '<:%q:>\n' "ls ${paramus[@]} -r" makes the way the splitting works. If you want to have the ls as a different argument the have it as one! printf '<:%q:>\n' "ls" "@{paramus[@]}" "-r". The double quotes around the ls and -r are optional, but the ones around ${paramus[@]} are required.

I'm genuinely curious what string(s) you wanted to get, because each time you put two spaces inside quotes. Quoted spaces will always be part(s) of some argument(s), never separators, this is the very point of quoting. So it seems you explicitly wanted these spaces inside some argument(s). But in the example you posted any space that is not a separator does not make sense. I'm pointing this out because your confusion may be not only with "how "${params[@]}" works", but also with broader "how quoting works" or even with "how sudo works".


params=(-l -t -a)
sudo "ls ${params[@]} -r"


Given the way you used those quotes there, it would appear that what you think you want is the * expansion, as opposed to the @ expansion. While @ expands each array element separately, * joins them into a single string(*).
This would pass printf (the format string and) the single argument ls -l -t -a -r, producing the output <ls -l -t -a -r>:
params=(-l -t -a)
printf "<%s>\n" "ls ${params[*]} -r"

However, that probably isn't what you want with most commands. E.g. doing the same but without the printf, trying to run ls:
params=(-l -t -a)
"ls ${params[*]} -r"

just gives an error to the tune of
bash: ls -l -t -a -r: command not found

This should not be surprising, as the quotes make the spaces act like regular characters. This is what you need to do with filenames that have spaces, but it's not too often one has a command with such a name.
Then again, you mentioned you wanted to keep the array elements separate:

Can this be easily/reasonably prevented to work as intended - keep the expanded array separate? Naive approaches like sudo "ls ""${params[@]}"" -r" or sudo 'ls '"${params[@]}"' -r' do not seem to work.

But again, you're using quotes to affix ls  and  -r to the strings expanded from the array. Back-to-back quoted strings concatenate into one (that's how e.g. 'ain'\''t so' works).
If you don't want that, don't do that. Instead, use the @ array expansion and keep the rest of the arguments separate:
params=(-l -t -a)
ls "${params[@]}" -r

You do have to double-quote the "${params[@]}" to prevent the shell stupidity of otherwise splitting individual elements on whitespace(**).
And since sudo also runs the given command directly using the arguments it gets, this is also how to do it with sudo:
params=(-l -t -a)
sudo ls "${params[@]}" -r

This would be different with e.g. ssh, which by necessity needs to pass a command line to the remote shell. There, the two args foo and bar would be same as the single arg foo bar, and you'll need to go through the quoting hell of making sure the remote shell interprets your command correctly.
See also:

How can we run a command stored in a variable?
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

(* Using the first character of the IFS shell variable as the joiner. By default, a space.)
(** Actually, splitting on characters found in the IFS shell variable. By default, space, tab and newline.)


"to prevent the shell stupidity of otherwise splitting individual elements on whitespace.". Not on whitespace, on $IFS and it only so happens that $IFS by default contains space, tab and newline characters, 3 (of many) whitespace characters. Similarly, "${array[*]}" does not join with space, but with the first character of $IFS (which, again, by default is the space character). More generally, when you leave a parameter expansion unquoted for its splitting effect or use "$*" for its joining effect, you need to consider what the current value of $IFS is.

@StéphaneChazelas, I know. It's whitespace for most people, and I didn't want to confuse the issue further with IFS here.

I see many people take that "simplification" approach when explaining this kind of thing but IMO, that leads to further misconception. Most people assume that that splitting is the same thing as would happen if the value of the parameter was entered literally, but IMO, it's important to understand that it's not and why.

@StéphaneChazelas, something I've mentioned in several answers wrt. quote processing, because that's a much bigger difference between word/field splitting and regular command line parsing (IMO, of course). But most people don't have a modified IFS and even here, they wouldn't need to care about it with the correct solution. Honestly, I'm not exactly convinced a random poster would even grok all the details even if we do tell them exactly what the gory details are...

Well, if you want sudo to run the "ls " command with "-l", "-t", "-a", and " -r" as argument, you need:
params=(-l -t -a)
sudo 'ls ' "${params[@]}" ' -r'

But why would you? I doubt your system has a command called "ls " with a space at the end.
If you want to call ls instead and its last argument to be "-r" instead of " -r", then it's just:
sudo ls "${params[@]}" -r

That is you need the space outside the quotes for it to be treated as the argument delimiter it is in the syntax of the shell language, and not be passed literally in the arguments to sudo.
You don't expect cmd "a${var}b" to call cmd with a, <contents-of-$var>, and b as separate arguments, so why would you expect cmd "a${array[@]}b" to when $array contains one element for instance?
The "${array[@]}" syntax causes the elements of the array to be separated out from each other, not from the text around it.


Bash groups expanded array with adjacent strings

Yes, in the case you present, it does.  This is documented:

If the subscript is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the word expands to all members of the array name. These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. If the word is double-quoted, ${name[*]} expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the IFS variable, and ${name[@]} expands each element of name to a separate word. When there are no array members, ${name[@]} expands to nothing. If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word.

You ask,

Can this be easily/reasonably prevented to work as intended - keep the expanded array separate?

If you mean that you want a leading string, each array element, and a trailing string, all as separate words, then sure.  In that case, you have worked against yourself by making the original a single word, and you can get what you seem to be asking for by just not doing that:
sudo ls "${params[@]}" -r

You also observe that

Naive approaches like sudo "ls ""${params[@]}"" -r" or sudo 'ls '"${params[@]}"' -r' do not seem to work.

, and of course you're right that those approaches produce the same expansion as your original.  But I suspect that either you've misstated what you want to achieve, or else you've lost sight of it.  If you want the ls, each element of params, and the -r all as separate words, then why are you quoting the whitespace at which the shell otherwise would split those words?  You've presented three different variations on that.  The solution is to avoid quoting whitespace at which you want the shell to split words.
If, on the other hand, you want the whole command as a single word, then use ${params[*]} instead of ${params[@]}:
sudo "ls ${params[*]} -r"

* indexing differs from @ indexing exactly and only in the case of expansion within double quotes.  With @ in that context, you get word splitting between elements (but not before the first or after the last), whereas with * in that context you normally* get a space between elements, but no word splitting there.

*More precisely, if special variable IFS is set then you get its first character, which defaults to a space, and if IFS is unset then you also get a space.  You can get a different character if the value of IFS has been modified.

Acknowledged, @StéphaneChazelas. I have updated this answer to clarify.

"You can get a different character if the value of IFS has been modified.". For completeness: or nothing at all if $IFS is set but empty.
